# An art gallery problem

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-geometry

An art gallery has the shape of a simple $n$-gon. Find the minimum number of watchmen needed to survey the building, no matter how complicated its shape be.

I failed to solve the problem. Please help in details.

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_gallery_problem). This is a famous problem, and is even one of the [Theorem of the Day](http://www.theoremoftheday.org/GeometryAndTrigonometry/ArtGallery/TotDArtGallery.pdf) problems.